# Using Bessel's inequality to prove the Riemann-Lebesgue lemna

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-series

Let $f$ and $f'$ be piecewise continuous function on $[-L,L]$. Use Bessel's inequality to show that
$$\lim_{ n\to \infty} \int_{-L}^L f(x)\cos \bigg(\frac{n \pi x}{L}\bigg) dx=\lim_{n\to  \infty} \int_{-L}^L f(x) \sin\bigg(\frac{n \pi x}{L}\bigg) dx=0$$

#### Progress

I wrote the fourier expansion of $f(x)$ then multiplied both sides by $f(x)$ and tried to integrate by parts, but was not able to get the desired result.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: You may want to check out [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) tutorial for typesetting your questions. :)

Comment: I wrote the fourier expansion of f(x) then multiplied both sides by f(x) and tried to integrate.

Comment: Did you try integration by part?

Comment: Yes thats what i tried but i am not able to get the desired result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example, for the first term, using integration by part

$$\int_{-L}^L f(x) \cos \bigg(\frac{n\pi x}{L}\bigg) dx = - \frac{L}{n\pi} \int_{-L}^L f'(x) \cos \bigg(\frac{n\pi x}{L}\bigg) dx $$

Note that now you have an $n$ at the bottom.

The integral on the right can be bounded:

$$\bigg| \int_{-L}^L f'(x) \cos \bigg(\frac{n\pi x}{L}\bigg) dx \bigg| \leq  \int_{-L}^L \bigg| f'(x) \cos \bigg(\frac{n\pi x}{L}\bigg)\bigg| dx \leq \int_{-L}^L | f'(x)| dx$$

Comment: since the lim n tends to infinity the right hand terms evaluates to zero. right?

Comment: Sort of. You need also to use $|\cos (y)| \leq 1$ so that the integral on the RHS of the equation is not depending on $n$. @PrachiD'souza

Comment: I am sorry i am not able to follow. Can you please show me step in more detail.

Comment: @PrachiD'souza : PLease see the edit.

Comment: But how we get the desired result from this?

Comment: @PrachiD'souza: What happens when you take $n\to \infty$?

Comment: I don't understand where it uses  Bessel's inequality

Answer (score 0):

These expressions are $a_n$ and $b_n$ in the Fourier Series (times L). If these limits did not equal 0 then the sum in Bessel's Inequality would diverge by the divergence test and the equality would be false.